# SuiteScript 2 restlet accessing with Node

Tags: oauth, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I need to call a SuiteScript restlet using Node with Oauth, I can't seem to find enough info. I have set up the "Integrations app" and I have the keys. Which Node Oauth is best suited for POST requests? We have npm Oauth 1 and 2, we have simple-OAuth etc. Then we have the form of passing the information which is different in each case as NetSuite has it's own requirements. I can't seem to hit the right combination to get this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks in advance for any help you may give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use Oauth.
Use "Authorization" header when sending request to RESTlet

for eg:

```
"Authorization" : 'NLAuth nlauth_account=******, nlauth_email=****, nlauth_signature=***, nlauth_role=3'
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I do need to use Oauth, it is a requirement of the client

Comment: Further, I am looking for Guidance to what Node package to use and an example of the request

Comment: Okay, then you could follow this.
http://blog.prolecto.com/2017/10/14/download-netsuite-oauth-token-based-authentication-sample-node-js-program/

Comment: Awesome that worked like a charm, thanks for your help